# How to add post count to wp_nav_menu?

Tags: posts, menus

Is it possible to add post count to menu links using wp_nav_menu?

For example:-

```
    Apple (3)
    ball (6)
    cat (2)
```

Comment: What exactly is this? Categories? Post Tags? Custom Taxonomy terms? Highly depends on what count you want to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the easiest thing should be a callback to the `start_el()` method of the Walker class.

```
// From core:
apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
```

Just grab the data (whatever the actual data is and from wherever it comes) and append it.

```
add_action( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse_10042_nav_menu_post_count', 10, 4 );
function wpse_10042_nav_menu_post_count( $output, $item, $depth, $args )
{
    // Check $item and get the data you need
    printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', var_export( $item, true ) );
    // Then append whatever you need to the $output
    $output .= '';

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/count-wp_nav_menu-items)?

```
$menu_to_count = wp_nav_menu(array(
    'echo' => false,
    'theme_location' => 'menu'
    ));
$menu_items = substr_count($menu_to_count,'class="menu-item ');
echo $menu_items;
```

Comment: Yes i saw it. Now i checked again. I think its not post count. It's menu count.