# How to add bubble count in WordPress wp_nav_menu menu?

Tags: menus, comments

I have to add a bubble notification in WordPress `wp_nav_menu` like the following code.

```
<ul>           
      <li> Tickets <span class="unread">2</span></li>

        <li> Log-out</li>
</ul>
```

Here I have to add this part in it.

```
<span class="unread">2</span>
```

I have seen this one and tried it.

```
add_action( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse_10042_nav_menu_post_count', 10, 4 );

 function wpse_10042_nav_menu_post_count( $output, $item, $depth, $args ) {

    $output .= '<span class="unread">'.my_function_here().'</span>';

    return $output;
}
```

And get it from here [How to add post count to wp_nav_menu?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100427/how-to-add-post-count-to-wp-nav-menu)

But the problem is its adding to every menu link. I want to add it to only one menu item. Not everyone in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For flexibility, you could assign the CSS *bubblecount* class to the corresponding menu item:

[image]

and then target it with:

```
if( in_array( 'bubblecount', (array) $item->classes ) )
    $output .= '<span class="unread">'.my_function_here().'</span>';
```

in your code snippet above.

Comment: can you tell me little elaborately. ?  I am not much experienced in it

Comment: sure, please check out the update @Akelya

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
function add_bubble_to_nav( $items, $args ) {
    $items .= '<span class="unread">stuff</span>';
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_bubble_to_nav', 10, 2 );
```

No need to use walker here, just go for the filter I think.

This adds it to the end of the menu. If you need it in a specific position you could go for `strpos` to find the position and then `substr_replace` to put it in there or something.

Comment: Thank you for your code. But it adds the stuff at the end of menu list. i want to add it to single menu item.  any idea, how to make it work on single menu only

Comment: Would need to know a little more about the menu's structure. But should be doable with `strpos` and `substr_replace`, just find the position where you want it and insert it in the `$items` at the wanted place.